# Python Equivalent of MATLAB's colon operator

Tags: python, matlab, vector

In MATLAB I can create monotonically spaced vectors as in the examples below using the `:`, colon,  operator. How can I do this in Python in a similarly concise manner?

```
>> x=1:10
x =
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
```

or

```
>> x=0:2:10
x =
     0     2     4     6     8    10
```

Comment: Use `range`. Mind the order of arguments in the three-input version, though. And note that Python's `range`, unlike Matlab's `:`, doesn't include the upper limit. Also, depending on what you want to do later you may want to convert the result to a `list`. See an example [here](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EIyezuESjKDEvPVXDSMfQUMdYU1Pz/38A)

Comment: Thanks Luis. Yes, list(range) produces what I want, though for float operations it seems I need to move to numpy, which appears to produce more MATLAB-like behavior. Your link is very useful, I've updated your example with the numpy equivalent [here!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EIyezuESjKDEvPVXDQMfQQMdIU1OTiysztyC/qEQhrzS3oJIrpcLWSM@UC6IeLKSXiNChnVKhk1Khqfn/PwA "Python 3 – Try It Online"). Is there a purpose for omitting the upper limit?

Comment: Yes, Numpy is more Matlab-like. As for why the upper limit is omitted, well, that's how Python is defined. I once read some motivation [here](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html) (but I wasn't totally convinced) :-)

Answer (score 5):

@karakfa is right in that this is the way to create a simple list.

Matlab's vectors and matrices offer vectorised computation, though, and if that's what you need, you should probably use `numpy.array`:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.arange(1, 11)
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, this method seems to work best for me as it allows floats as well as integers. Since the output doesn't include the upper limit this seems to require more overhead on the coder's part doesn't it? I would really need 3 lines of code to replicate MATLAB's simple operator. I hear Python is supposed to produce simpler code than MATLAB, but I'm not quite seeing it yet.
`import numpy` 
`dx=2.5` 
`print(numpy.arange(0,10+dx,dx))`

Comment: I thought the same as you initially, but for a zero-indexed language, it actually does exactly what you want most of the time. If you want a range of 10 integers, you get ten integers. To be honest, though, I hardly ever use the range function. In the specific domain of mathematics applications, I imagine that you might have a point about one-indexing, but it depends on your use case.

Answer (score 3):

there is range

```
range([start], stop[, step])
```

`[]` shows optional arguments.  Default ranges starts with zero

Comment: Note that while Matlab indexes from 1, Python (and nearly every other programming language) indexes from 0.

Comment: @MartinSandChristensen mathematics-oriented languages usually start indexing from 1: aside from MATLAB, some are: Scilab (indexing similar to MATLAB), Fortran (1-based by default), Wolfram (indices ≤0 have special meaning), Maple (mathematical indexing always 1-based, programmer indexing by default).

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
list(range(0,11,2))
```

because `range` is an immutable iterable object.

Comment: That _should_ depends on his use case.

Comment: Probably. Anyway, I prefer your solution with numpy, it makes more sense if OP wants to translte Matlab/Octave code to python.