# Syntax error when plotting in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matplotlib

I am working on translating some code from Matlab into Python. I am a little bit confused in terms of understanding this Matlab code:

```
plot(m_true(1,[1:p 1]), m_true(2,[1:p 1]),'*', 'Color',[0 0 0])
```

When I try to translate that into Python it looks something like this:

```
plot(m_true[1,(1:p, 1)], m_true[2,(1:p 1)],'*', 'Color',[0, 0, 0])
```

The colon causes a syntax error. Can anyone who has plotting experience in Matlab (I am new to this language) explain the matlab syntax (in terms of what the indexing of 1:p is doing) and perhaps how to fix the syntax error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Matlab, the colon operator describes a range between the two values n and m of a container.

For example, given a vector `x = {4,2,67,2,5,26}`, the following expression takes the values 3 through 6 and saves them in the vector y:

```
y = x(3:6)
```

resulting in the following values for y:

```
67   2   5   26
```

Another use of it is to index all elements of one dimension of a matrix:

```
x = rand(5,5)
x(:,1) = 1
```

would fill the first column of the matrix m with the following:

```
1.0000    0.9649    0.8003    0.9595    0.6787
1.0000    0.1576    0.1419    0.6557    0.7577
1.0000    0.9706    0.4218    0.0357    0.7431
1.0000    0.9572    0.9157    0.8491    0.3922
1.0000    0.4854    0.7922    0.9340    0.6555
```

Heres a simplified version of your plotting function:

```
plot(m(1,[1:3 1]),'*', 'Color',[0 0 0])
```

which plots values 1 to 3 of the first row of x and afterwards the first value (indicated by the space in the square brackets)
The output plot looks like this:

[image: plot(m(1,[1:3 1]),'*', 'Color',[0 0 0])]

changing the plot to

```
plot(x(1,[3:4 1]),'*')
```

(discarding the coloring here for better comparison)
would plot the values at index 3 and 4 with the additional value at index 1 like this:

[image: new values in yellow]

As for the import in python, you might have to use "range" as described in this post: 
[Python Equivalent of MATLAB's colon operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49211607/python-equivalent-of-matlabs-colon-operator)

I hope this helps,
cheers,
Simon

Comment: That was super helpful! Thank you for taking the time to explain!

Comment: Glad I could help :)